# Open Child Window on click with Main window as parent - Electron js

Tags: javascript, electron

I am working on small electron js application , i am trying to open the child on click from the main window

i am made a one ipc channel to send the onclick message from index.html to main.js file
from main js file i created the child window with main window as parent

> Due to hoisting and browser widow should not created before the app
> ready issue i am unable to create the child window along with parent
> window

i attached the code below for child browser window

Index.html

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link"  onclick="createChildWindow('./electron.html')">Electron</a>
</li>

// ipc channel to send the onclick event to main.js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
function createChildWindow (fileName) {
  ipcRenderer.send("createChildWindow", fileName)
}
```

Main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

// parent window creation
var parentWindow;
function createWindow () {
  parentWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1800,
    height: 1800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  parentWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow('index.html')

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow('index.html')
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

// receive onclick event message in channel and call the function
ipcMain.on("createChildWindow", (e, fileName)=>{
  createChildWindow(fileName)
})

// function to create a child window
var childWindow;
function createChildWindow(fileName) {
  childWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000,
    webPreferences: {
      parent : parentWindow, // accessing the parent window 
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    }
  })
  childWindow.loadFile(fileName)
}
```

Along with this having another issue as well , i am using pouchdb for this application , when i open the file which used the db in the child window returning the error as

`IO error: lock DB/Adb/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable`

This is due to when we open the db in two process it will trow the error

can anyone help me to solve this both the issue

Comment: `parent` option [seems to be](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) root level property, not `webPreferences` property.

Comment: Thanks @pergy while mentioning parent in root level its worked